# Jquery Cycle2 Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, carousel

I have this problem with a HTML slideshow script (CYCLE2):

I need that the slideshow stops when there are only two pics inside (cause it's useless continue in loop with the same pics)

```
 <div class="slideshow" 
        data-cycle-fx=carousel
        data-cycle-timeout=3000
        data-cycle-speed="800"
        data-cycle-slides="> div"
        >
        <!-- empty element for pager links -->
        <div><img src="images/img1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="images/img2.jpg" /></div>
        <!-- <div><img src="images/img3.jpg" /></div> 
        <div><img src="images/img4.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="images/img5.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img src="images/img6.jpg" /></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

**js:**

```
 <script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

i tried with jquery and count the images..

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var images = [
'<img src="images/crd-assaeroporti.jpg">',
'<img src="images/crd-aci.jpg">',
'<img src="images/crd-malpensa.jpg">',
'<img src="images/crd-napoli.jpg">',
'<img src="images/crd-linate.jpg">',
'<img src="images/crd-torino.jpg">',
'<img src="images/manu.jpg">'
 ];
for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
      $('.slideshow').cycle('add', images[i]);
  }
$(this).prop('disabled', true)
 if(images.length <= 6){
  alert("Hello\nHow are you?");
 }
 });
 </script>
 <div class="credits">
  <span>Garantito da</span>
  <div class="slideshow" 
   data-cycle-fx=carousel
  data-cycle-timeout=3000
  data-cycle-speed="800"
  data-cycle-slides="> img"
   >
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to do? It's good to attempt something rather than just asking us to come up with a solution.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: i just added my attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
if(images.length === 2){
   $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle({loop: 1});
}

// loop = 1 , number of times cycle will loop, 0 will loop continuously.
```